# The columns for my images got out of wack, and started it in another row. What might have caused that?

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a portfolio website, and everything has gone smoothly and was looking really nice. When, bam! The columns (or rows, maybe?) got out of wack and put what's the 5th image link after the 6th. There's only 6, so having it where a 7th would be is super confusing, not to mention doesn't look good. The images are formatted to 16:9 (1920 x 1080), and entered into the site with a width of 960 and a height of 540. Everything was formatted properly, and was working, but for some reason stopped. I haven't added any code other than fixing file names.

I blocked out the name cause it's my girlfriend's portfolio and not mine. I don't care if y'all know my name, but I'm trying to keep her privacy a bit. But the image was too big, so I uploaded it to imgur so I can paste the link for you to see.

https://imgur.com/RLFJRWq

I tried reformatting all the images to make sure they were in the right dimensions, and double checking my code that I didn't accidentally press a key somewhere and mess up some code. However nothing I've tried has worked. I even tried checking one of my backups of code to see if starting from where I did before today's session would work. But after going to the backup and updating file names, same thing!

All this code is used a total of 6 times, and the other 5 iterations are working just fine. It's just this one that's having an issue.

HTML having an issue

```
        <div class = "column">
           <div class = "container">
              <a href = "olympics.html" target = "_blank">
                 <img src = "om-cover.jpg" width = "960" height = "540" class = "image" style = "width: 100%">
                 <div class = "middle">
                    <div class = "text"> Olympics </div>
                 </div>
              </a>
           </div>
        </div>
```

CSS for what makes that image link so fancy

```
.column {
   float: left;
   width: 49.5%;
   padding: 3.5px;
}

.row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .column {
      width: 100%;
   }
}

/* Image Hovering */
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #FFE8C2;
}

.image {
   opacity: 1;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   transition: .5s ease;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.middle {
   transition: .5s ease;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.container:hover .image {
   opacity: 0.3;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.container:hover .middle {
   opacity: 1;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
   background-color: #395642;
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 16px 32px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I’m finding difficulty following what is happening. Where does .row come into it and how do you want the system to deal with that padding on different viewport widths? Please create a runnable snippet.see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or maybe step back, start again and work with grid or flex rather than float.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not 100% what .row does. I followed a short tutorial on how to get it to format like that and it was working til it stopped. It stopped working shortly after I rounded the corners. It just kinda broke. I've upload an image to imgur and pasted the link here. But the issue is that it actually added a whole blank space to the site, and I don't know where it came from. https://imgur.com/a/IU2oMtD

Edit: sorry for taking so long, I was between laptops shortly after posing this.